# Pay Transparency Law broken by company that hired me in Connecticut. Recourse?

Tags: salary, hiring-process

### Short Version

Applied to a company, got hired for a below average salary for my profession, realized they broke a law by not disclosing the salary range for the position. Can I do anything about it?

### Long Version

I applied to job about 3 months ago at a large (200+) company in Connecticut. In the job description on Indeed, they failed to disclose the salary range as required in Connecticut HB 6380.

At the time, I had been unemployed for several months and was desperate to get a paycheck for my family, so I didn't care to bring this up. After a few interview rounds, I asked what the salary range was, and didn't get a response.

During the last interview, the HR hiring manager asked what my salary requirements were. Again, I was desperate, and at this point quite nervous. They told me it was between myself and another candidate, so I felt pressured to say a lower salary than I should have.

The offer letter came a few days later with the salary being the lowest end of the range I gave.

Now I'm on the team, and I really enjoy it. However, the whole salary negotiation (if you can call it that) left a bad taste in my mouth. I feel like I got taken for a ride, and now I make less than I should.

Is there any legal course of action I can take at this point to increase my salary? Preferably without jeopardizing my job.

Comment: VTC for this being essentially Legal advise. However, I will give 2c here. Unless you have it in writing where you asked for a Salary range disclosure and they didn't reply, you don't have a leg to stand on. Best advice - work hard and then when it comes time for annual review, present a business case as to why you should be paid more.

Comment: You chose to underbid, and then accepted an offer on that basis. I'm sorry, but that's the way salary negotiation works, and that's what you agreed to in order to seal the deal. I don't think you have a legal leg to stand on, but if you want to waste money asking a lawyer feel free to do so. Better approach is the one @TheDemonLord suggested -- prove your value to your manager and to the company and try to get them to give you a larger raise at review time.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the law you're citing may only require them to disclose the salary range if you ask them to do so. You didn't. I'd have a hard time arguing against the claim that this, too, was your choice at the time. A technicality is not

Comment: I'd also add that immediately threatening your employer with lawyers is a good way to not have an employer.

Comment: I'm not an attorney, but I just read HB 6380 and it would appear to me that they complied with items 8 and 9, which are probably what you're basing your argument on. To me, it looks like they had no requirement to disclose the salary range prior to your asking for it or their offering you the position, which appears to be exactly what happened. You didn't ask, so they didn't tell. You gave them a number and they made you an offer based on that number and then disclosed the salary range at the time they made you the offer. It seems pretty clear cut to me that they followed the law.

Comment: Unfortunately, you got what you negotiated for. Hopefully you can either negotiate for more at your first opportunity, or find another job more in line with your salary expectations. Either way, I sincerely wish you luck.

Comment: Discreetly consult a labor law attorney in your state to see what options you have.

Comment: I would agree with others, that by providing a salary range you would accept, you negotiate a salary with the potential employers. I can see both sides of the coin, by providing them a salary range you would accept, and by offering a salary in that range they by default disclosed the positions salary range. In the other hand, you also asked, but were desperate so you didn’t insist on getting an answer to their salary range before providing them your salary range. To be frank, you were desperate, so you accepted a job without negotiating a salary you would ultimately be happy with.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any legal course of action I can take at this point to increase my salary?

Maybe. You need to consult a lawyer. While they may have violated article (8) when they didn't disclose the range when you asked, it would be a tricky case to make (sorry, we forgot). The law also doesn't seem to spell out any consequences of breaking this provision, so it's unclear what the employer would be on the hook for other than the disclosure itself.

> Preferably without jeopardizing my job.

**Impossible**. Taking legal action against your employer is in most cases a career ending move not only at that employer but it will often significantly reduce your chances of finding a job elsewhere too. No employer likes to be sued and hence legal action is a means of last resort: do it only if the damage/benefit warrants it and if all else has failed.

Connecticut is an at-will state. If you take legal action, you will be out in less than a year, as soon as they can make it appear to not be retaliation.

> I feel like I got taken for a ride,

That feels overly dramatic. A salary negotiation is a mutual activity and you didn't negotiate well. The employer deployed pretty much "standard practice".

> and now I make less than I should.

Quite possibly. But the good news is that you like the job. There are "normal" ways to increase your compensation: do good work, carefully document your performance and your impact on the company, read up on salary ranges in your job and region etc. Bring all of this to your next performance review and engage your boss in a "career development" and "compensation strategy" discussion.

Since you just have agreed to a salary, it's not great to bring this up right away. You may have to sit this out until the next formal performance review which could be up to one year. I'm afraid you have to accept this as a learning experience. Prep better for your next negotiation.